# JQuery Searchable onSearchEmpty Need to Show a Button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I have a button I want to make it visible when the search will returned no result, so that the product can be added to the data table.

I have tried with  onSearchEmpty: to show this but this is not working.

Please suggest as the  onSearchEmpty which is the core function for jQuery searchbale did not seems to be working .

Thanks!

```js
$(function () {
    $( '#table' ).searchable({
        striped: true,
        oddRow: { 'background-color': '#f5f5f5' },
        evenRow: { 'background-color': '#fff' },
        searchType: 'fuzzy'
    });
    
    $( '#searchable-container' ).searchable({
        searchField: '#container-search',
        selector: '.row',
        childSelector: '.col-xs-4',
        show: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideDown(100);
        },
        hide: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideUp( 100 );
        },
         onSearchEmpty: function() {
         $('#shBtnAddNewProd').show();
   
     }
    })
});
```

```css
.row-padding {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/master/dist/jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
             <h3>Search and add product on the fly</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <input type="search" id="search" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a name of product">
            <span class="linkTextboxBotton"> <a type="button" class="btn-success btn-xs" id="shBtnAddNewProd" style="display: none"> + add as new product </a> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table" id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Qty. </th>
                        <th>Disc. % </th>
      <th>Sum: </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pro1</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>$0</td>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Pro2</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>$0</td>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pro4</td>
                        <td>400</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>$0</td>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried onSearchEmpty but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess you misinterpret the meaning with `onSearchEmpty`. It is supposed to be triggered when the *search term* is empty. There is actually no callbacks for the search "results".

Second, you can skip the entire `$( '#searchable-container' ).searchable({ })` and work on  `$( '#table' ).searchable({ })` only. I guess it was some kind of test?

Third, when there is no callbacks for the search, you must create that yourself. This searchable plugin does nothing but updating the rows `display`, the same will your slideup / down do. You can create a generic handler like this :

```
var emptySearch = function(element, term) {
   var total = element.find('tbody tr').length;
   var hidden = element.find('tbody tr:hidden').length;
   if (total == hidden) {
      $('#shBtnAddNewProd').show()
   } else {
      $('#shBtnAddNewProd').hide()
   }
}
```

And use it as callback

```
$( '#table' ).searchable({
    striped: true,
    oddRow: { 'background-color': '#f5f5f5' },
    evenRow: { 'background-color': '#fff' },
    searchType: 'fuzzy',
    onSearchActive: emptySearch,  // <---here
    onSearchEmpty: emptySearch,   // and here
    show: function( elem ) {
        elem.slideDown(100);
    },
    hide: function( elem ) {
        elem.slideUp( 100 );
    },
});
```

Now it works, more or less -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o9tj0g31/**
Less because the plugin does a poor job on triggering the callbacks. Some times an extra `keyup` is needed.  I see no reason for optimizing a 5 year old jQuery plugin no longer maintained.

You could perhaps change `emptySearch` to work directly on the table, not the passed element, and by that trigger the hide/show also on blur and focus.

Comment: Everything working fine but the button is not showing. I am using jQuery v2.2.2. Please check this link http://webapplications.co.in/nextstep/deal.html

Comment: @Middlerange, I dont know what I should look for on that page..?